# AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getchildren'

Tags: python, pandas, api

I'm trying to query/search data from the FREDAPI, but when using the `.search` function, I get the following error.

```py
fred.search('S&P')
```

```
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getchildren'
```

I've tried downgrading the python version by setting up a new virtual environment, but it didn't work.

Comment: What version of python are you using? [`Element.getchildren`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren) has been deprecated since 3.2 and was set to be removed in 3.9.

Comment: I'm currently using 3.10, I also tried 3.9. Should I be using version 3.8?

Comment: Either use 3.8 or earlier or install a `fredapi` version past 0.4.3. [Which is where 3.9 support was added](https://github.com/mortada/fredapi/releases)

Comment: @Axe319 upgrading the fredapi to the new version worked! thank you so much